# Get Select Value in textfield As Well As On Change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm just learning Mysql/PHP and I'm trying to update a textfield depending on the selected value from the dropdownlist. I have read through several tutorials, and tried to apply them, but I cannot get this working...

Dont mind my messy code, will clean later !!!

Page with dropdown list  and texfields:

```html
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    include("/includes/connect.php");
    $sql="SELECT id, nr, model, serienummer, capaciteit, persoon, opmerking, datumuitgeleend, datumretour FROM ipads WHERE uitgeleend='Ja' ORDER BY nr";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    if(isset($_POST['btnAdd'])) {
        $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
        $persoon=$_POST['persoon'];
        $datumuitgeleend=$_POST['datumuitgeleend'];
        $datumretour=$_POST['datumretour'];
        $opmerking=$_POST['opmerking'];
        $sql="UPDATE ipads SET uitgeleend='Ja', persoon='$persoon', datumuitgeleend='$datumuitgeleend', datumretour='$datumretour', opmerking='$opmerking' WHERE id='$id'";
        $result=$db->query($sql);
        header("location:index.php");

    }
    include("/includes/get_header.php");
?>

            <h1 class="page-title">iPad uitlenen</h1>
                    <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a> </li>
            <li class="active">Nieuw</li>
        </ul>
        </div>

<form id="gegevensForm" class="col-xs-4" form method="POST" action="ipad-uitlenen.php">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Selecteer leen iPad</label>
    <select name="id" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Selecteer een leen iPad</option>
    <?php foreach($result as $row): ?>
        <option data-datumuitgeleend="<?= $row['datumuitgeleend']; ?>" data-datumretour ="<?= $row['datumretour']; ?>" data-opmerking="<?= $row['opmerking']; ?>" data-persoon="<?= $row['persoon']; ?>" value="<?= $row['id']; ?>"><?= $row['nr']; ?> / <?= $row['serienummer']; ?> / <?= $row['model']; ?> / <?= $row['capaciteit']; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Naam</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="persoon" value="" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Datum uitgeleend</label>
        <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="form-control" name="datumuitgeleend" value="" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Datum retour</label>
        <input type="text" id="datepicker1" class="form-control" name="datumretour" value="" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comment">Opmerking</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="opmerking" value=""></textarea>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" name="btnAdd" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Opslaan</button>
    <a href="index.php"><input type="button" name="btnCancel" value="Annuleer" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"></a>
    <?php
        include('../includes/get_footer.php');
    ?>

</form>

<?php
}
?>
```

**get_header.php**

```html
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Admin Control Panel</title>
    <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/premium.css">
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/demos/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 
 <script src="lib/jQuery-Knob/js/jquery.knob.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 
 <script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $("select[name='id']").on('change',function() {
    $("input[name='persoon']").val($(this ).children(":selected").data( "persoon" ));
    $("input[name='datumretour']").val($(this ).children(":selected").data( "datumretour" ));
    $("input[name='datumuitgeleend']").val($(this ).children(":selected").data( "datumuitgeleend" ));
    $("input[name='opmerking']").val($(this ).children(":selected").data( "opmerking" ));
   ; })
  ;})
 </script>
 
</head>
<body class=" theme-blue">

    <style type="text/css">
        #line-chart {
            height:300px;
            width:800px;
            margin: 0px auto;
            margin-top: 1em;
        }
        .navbar-default .navbar-brand, .navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover { 
            color: #fff;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var uls = $('.sidebar-nav > ul > *').clone();
            uls.addClass('visible-xs');
            $('#main-menu').append(uls.clone());
        });
    </script>

 <script>
  $(function() {
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
   $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
  });
 </script>
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $(".knob").knob();
        });
    </script>
 
 
    <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="" href="index.html"><span class="navbar-brand"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span> iPad Control Panel</span></a></div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="height: 1px;">
          <ul id="main-menu" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown hidden-xs">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user padding-right-small" style="position:relative;top: 3px;"></span>
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </a>

              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="dropdown-header">Admin Panel</li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="logout.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i> Logout</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    

    <div class="sidebar-nav">
    <ul>
 <li><a href="index.php" class="nav-header"><img src="./images/ipad.png" width="16" height="16">  Overzicht iPads</a></li>
 <li><ul class="dashboard-menu nav nav-list collapse in">
            <li><a href="ipad-beschikbaar.php"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span> Beschikbaar</a></li>
   <li><a href="ipad-uitgeleend.php"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span> Uitgeleend</a></li>
   <li><a href="ipad-geschiedenis.php"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span> Geschiedenis</a></li>
    </ul></li>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="stats">
</div>
```

Table :

[click here for table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtMZ9.png)

Site :

[Click here for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADhGj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the on change value with php you have you reload the page if the select box changes a better alternative would be to use js.

You could do something like:

```
$("select[name='id']").on('change',function()
    {$("input[name='persoon']").val($(this).val()); //this will put the select value in text field
})
```

the above code will put select `$row['id']` in text box if you want `$row['persoon']` to be updated you might want to update your `option` html first to have `$row['persoon']` as any of the attribute something like

```
<option data-datumuitgeleend="<?= $row['datumuitgeleend']; ?>" data-datumretour ="<?= $row['datumretour']; ?>" data-opmerking="<?= $row['opmerking']; ?>" data-persoon="<?= $row['persoon']; ?>" value="<?= $row['id']; ?>"><?= $row['nr']; ?> / <?= $row['serienummer'];
```

an you javascript should update this value like use:

```
$("select[name='id']").on('change',function( {    $("input[name='persoon']").val($(this ).children(":selected").data( "persoon" ));
    $("textarea[name='opmerking']").html($(this ).children(":selected").data( "opmerking" ));
    $("input[name='datumretour']").val($(this ).children(":selected").data( "datumretour" ));
    $("input[name='datumuitgeleend']").val($(this ).children(":selected").data( "datumuitgeleend" ));
})
```

If you're not using jQuery Way to do in plain js:

```
var select =document.getElementsByName('id')[0];
select.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var options = this.options;
    var persoon = options[options.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-persoon');
    document.getElementsByName('persoon')[0].value = attr;
    var datumuitgeleend= options[options.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-datumuitgeleend');
    document.getElementsByName('datumuitgeleend')[0].value = attr;
    var opmerking= options[options.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-opmerking');
    document.getElementsByName('opmerking')[0].value = attr;
            var datumretour = options[options.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-datumretour');
    document.getElementsByName('datumretour')[0].value = attr;

}
```

And also change your sql select statement to have datumretour, datumuitgeleend,

```
$sql="SELECT id, nr, model, serienummer, capaciteit, datumretour, datumuitgeleend, persoon, opmerking FROM ipads WHERE uitgeleend='Ja' ORDER BY nr";
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I've been messing around with my code and can't seem to get it working. Could you please add the solution you provied in my code and put it here? Sorry if I ask too much...

Comment: I did, see edit. Did not work? In textfield name="person" should display a name related to the selected dropdown value. It does nothing? Hope u understand?

Comment: Edited get_header.php see above, still doesn't work? Any idea .. :( ?

Comment: try to put it before other `scripts` ie, after `<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: That worked! Now, how do I apply this to the textfields : datumuitgeleend, datumretour and opmerking? And does the order of scripts really matter ?????

Comment: I edited my post, I added screenshots of my table and what I see now. As you can see, I can see the name that is linked to the selected value from the dropdown list. I also want to apply this to the last 3 textfields : datumuitgeleend, datumretour and opmerking. Hope u understand ...

Comment: It seems to work! Only problem now is that it doesnt get 'opmerking'. Is it because It cant be inserted into a <textarea> ?

Comment: yes that's because textarea doesn't have `val` property but we can update the `inner html` of text area...check out the updated `script` it should work

Comment: np..happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

I did mind the messy code, but mostly the lack of minimum code to reproduce the problem you are facing, so forgive me if I did not distill your question properly.

I think the problem you describe boils down to "how to populate a `<textarea>` whenever the chosen `<select>` option changes?"

```js
$(function() {
  var select = $('select[name="pickAnOption"]');

  function update(select) {
    var value = select.val(),
        textarea = $('textarea[name="describeTheOption"]');

    if (value) {
      textarea.attr('disabled', false).text('You picked ' + value);
    }
    else {
      textarea.attr('disabled', true).text('Pick an option first');
    }
  }

  select.on('change', function() {
    update(select);
  });
  update(select);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Choose wisely: 
  <select name="pickAnOption">
    <option value="">Pick one</option>
    <option value="a">option A</option>
    <option value="b">option B</option>
    <option value="c">option C</option>
  </select>

  <br>
  
  Gives some options:
  <textarea name="describeTheOption"></textarea>
 </form>
```

As to explain what is going on, here's the flow of the javascript broken down into pieces

- `$(function() {`, this function is executed when the document is ready (all elements are available, assets such as images/stylesheet may or may not be loaded yet)
- `var select = ...`, store a reference to the `<select>` element as we will be using it multiple times and don't fancy to look it up constantly
- `function update() {..}`, as we want to update both on changes *and* the first time the page is loaded (as some browsers remember form state across page refresh), we want a function to call for these occasions
- `var value = select.val()`, take the selected option value
- `(var) textarea = $(..)`, store a reference to the textarea
- `if (value)`, if an option with a non-false(-ish) value (in this example: *value is not the empty value we've added to the 'Pick one' option*), execute the code in this block
- `$(textarea).attr('disabled', false)` make sure the textarea becomes editable (not disabled)
- `.text('You picked ' + value)`, set the contents of the textarea to display the option value
- `else`, pretty much the same as above, but acting on a non-value (disabling the textarea, setting a default text).
- `select.on('change', function() {..})`, listen to change events on the `<select>` element and trigger the `update` when another option is picked
- `update(select)`, initially trigger the `update` to ensure the textarea is on par with the selected option.

It is a matter of taste if you like to have the initial `update` (I prefer to do this), it would save one additional function if you don't.

Or you could use an alternative notiation, should you want to prevent a stand-alone function, for example

```
$('select[name="pickAnOption"]')
  .on('change', function() {
    //  update code here.
  })
  .change(); // invoke the change handler immediately
```